# Variable no definida PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, php-5.6

Al momento de cargar la página de Login en PHP me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: Variable no definida]

La variable la tengo definida más arriba en el código como se muestra a continuación:

```
<?php
    //importación de conexion
    require "conexion.php";

    //Iniciar session
    session_start();
    

    if($_POST){
        
        //Obtener usuario y password
        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        //Revisar si el usuario existe
        $sql = "SELECT id, passwd, nombre, tipo_usuario FROM usuario WHERE usuario='$usuario'";
        $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
        $num = $resultado->num_rows;
    }
    
?>
```

eh intentado definir la variable más abajo, sin embargo el error se arrastra a otras líneas del código.

Luego ocupo la variable en el formulario mas abajo quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
                                            <?php 

                                               
                                             if($num>0){
                                                //resultados de consulta
                                                $row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
                                                $password_bd = $row['passwd'];
                                                // Cifrar password SHA1
                                                $pass_c = sha1($password);
                                                //validación de password
                                                if($password_bd == $pass_c){
                                                  
                                                    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
                                                    $_SESSION['nombre'] = $row['nombre'];
                                                    $_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] = $row['tipo_usuario'];
                                    
                                                    //Redireccionamiento a sitio
                                                    header("Location: dashboard.php");
                                                }else{
                                                    ?><center> <p style="color:red"> "Usuario o contraseña inválido"</p></center> <?php
                                                }
                                            }else{
                                                ?><center> <p style="color:red"> "Usuario o contraseña inválido"</p></center> <?php
                                            }
                                                                                       
                                            ?>
```

Nota: el código está funcionando de forma correcta, sin embargo, me aparece el error al cargar la página.

Comment: ¿Cómo se relaciona el código de arriba con el de abajo?

Comment: Cambia `if($_POST)` por `if(!empty($_POST))`.

Comment: El error sigue apareciendo si utilizo este método.

Comment: @A.Cedano ambos códigos son parte del mismo archivo, un login. No pude subir el código completo, porque el sitio de stackoverflow encuentra que tiene mucho código.

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema es que `$num` solo existe cuando se accede a la pagina con `POST` ( al enviar el formulario ). Si accedes normalmenete a la página, como no hay `$_POST`, no entra en el if y no se crea la variable `$num`.

Lo que puedes hacer, antes de comprobar el valor de `$num` es comprobar si num existe con `isset`

```
if(isset($num)){
//Aquí ya sabemos que $num existe, con lo cual puedes hacer la comparación
    if($num > 0){
        ... //Tu lógica de cuando num es mayor a 0
    }
    else{
        ... //Tu lógica de cuando num existe pero no es mayor a 0
    } 
}
```